# jumping to element animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

right now I have a div with a id of "sidebar" and I am using css to add a hover class to add a bullet to the links on hover. The problem is I dont want the bullet to appear to "skip' between the links in the sidebar. I want the bullet to appear to follow your curser on a y-axis when you enter the sidebar. How can I do this with jquery?

html

```
    <div id="sidebar">
            <dl class="nice vertical tabs">
                  <dd><a href="#BiblesandCommentaries">الانجيل-تعليقات</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#EnquirersLibrary">الاستفسارات</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#NewBelievers">مؤمنون جدد</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#ChristianLiving">حياة المسيحى</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#FamilyLibrary">مكتبة الأسرة</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#YoungAdultLibrary">مكتبة الشباب</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#WorshipLibrary">مزامير وتراتيل</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#BibleTeachings">التدريس</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#Leadership">القيادة</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#SchoolofChrist">مدرسة الإنجيل</a> </dd>
                  <dd><a href="#MinorityLanguages">فهم المسيح</a> </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

css

```
#sidebar .tabs a:hover:after {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ;
-moz-transition: all 1s ;
-ms-transition: all 1s ;
-o-transition: all 1s ;
transition: all 1s ;
content: ""; 
display: block; 
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-top: 5px solid transparent; 
border-left: 10px solid white; 
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent; 
position: relative; 
bottom: 5px; 
margin-left: -20px; 
}
```

Comment: don't understand "dont want the bullet to appear to "skip' between the links" can you put it into a fiddle?

Comment: it will appear on hover of a link but will disappear until the next link is hovered. I want the bullet always visible when you enter the div with an id of "sidebar" but appear to follow your mouse on a y-axis

Comment: You've tagged the question with CSS, but not shown us any.. That might help..

Comment: @Blainer I've put it into this http://jsfiddle.net/U6DUn/ try to put it into SSCCE, the code you provided doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where or do you need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcfhH/1/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XcfhH/1/embedded/result/

Comment: that is what I have now. I want it to do that but have a transition animation when you hover to the next element.

Comment: I am not getting what you are telling. Please elaborate it a little bit. Previously your menu was showing glitches when we hove on anchor tag, i fixed it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XcfhH/1/ but know what you want i m bit confused.